# What is this script attempting to do?

Tags: wordpress

I have just been given access to a site to maintain, so the first thing I thought I'd do is some updates. After checking Wordfence it complained about a script which contained a file with the following within it:

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Script47/a467663c5c5e15f82b25d42f4e834e58)

Script was too big, I had to create a GIST as it went over the character limit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions should be self-contained. This question (and its answers) are of no use as soon as the gists fail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you pop that script into a base64 decoder you get:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/914d5c5a82252dc0235995e32147c9d9

This is a reverse web shell that gives a lot of access to the server. So far, I see Server Security Information, PHP information, a PHP shell, a File Manager for uploading and downloading malicious files, a server wide search function, and an SQL browser.

Comment: Did you use http://www.unphp.net/ ? Because I'm not able to decode it by this way

Comment: @lapinousexy Nope, I used https://www.base64decode.org/ to decode the base64 portion of the php script and then went from there. I don't think utilities like unphp.net support encoding/decoding.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to find out how/who posted this?

Comment: @Script47 That's a tough question. You could search your web server logs for access to that specific file but that might not get you much (an IP address at best). I think you're better off just wiping the server and reinstalling wordpress to a clean and up to date version.

Comment: @Script47 If I had to guess, this script could be used as insurance for a freelancer to obtain site development/maintenance payment. You could ask who created the site.